# Как суммировать элементы массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Как суммировать элементы массива таким образом

```
`Collection {#263 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#275 ▼
      +"platform": "Google"
      +"positive": "10"
      +"negative": "5"
      +"blocked": "1"
    }
    1 => {#274 ▼
      +"platform": "Yandex"
      +"positive": "6"
      +"negative": "2"
      +"blocked": "1"
    }
    2 => {#269 ▼
      +"platform": "Google"
      +"positive": "15"
      +"negative": "35"
      +"blocked": "23"
    }
  ]
}`
```

что бы получить

```
`Collection {#263 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#274 ▼
      +"platform": "Yandex"
      +"positive": "6"
      +"negative": "2"
      +"blocked": "1"
    }
    1 => {#269 ▼
      +"platform": "Google"
      +"positive": "25"
      +"negative": "40"
      +"blocked": "24"
    }
  ]
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array_values(array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    foreach($item as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($carry[$item['platform']][$k])) {
            if (is_numeric($v)) $carry[$item['platform']][$k] += $v;
        }
        else $carry[$item['platform']][$k] = $v;
    }

    return $carry;
}, []));

print_r($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/ZJu8B

Comment: У меня почему то выдает array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @Денис, вероятно, вам нужно будет определить свой массив до использования функций. Откуда вы берете данные?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/823jPjKh9M03vm

$reviews = \DB::table('reviews')->where('company_id', $id)->select('platform', 'positive', 'negative', 'blocked')->get();

Comment: Покажите, как вы используете мою функцию?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4pPpZSojEKNA

Comment: http://joxi.ru/V2VeZegTdMoaZm

Comment: @Денис, попробуйте передавать `$platforms['items']` вместо `$platforms`.

Comment: @Денис, хотя точно не знаю в чем проблема у вас

Comment: Дело в том что items там нет, это от laravel идет, у меня обычный массив http://joxi.ru/YmEkxk0Twey3oA

Comment: Привел массив к такому виду http://joxi.ru/E2pk4k9T7bN1Gm , так может проще сделать?

Comment: @Денис, привели к такому виду, пробуйте теперь мою функцию

Comment: Заработало!!!
От души спасибо!